# How to implement polymorphic boost program options class?

Tags: c++, boost, polymorphism

I am relatively new to object inheritance, I am aware of rule of 0/3/5, but I have always avoided deriving classes and mainly wrote codes applying rule of 0.

I have a large package which seems to have memory leak with a class from the library it uses that handles program options via boost library. Someone declared boost::program_options::options_description as pointer and my guess is that something is off with the destructor destroying the raw pointer once this class is used in multiple derivations and slicing. I almost never use pointers apart from std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr, so I have decided to reimplement the entire class from scratch.

The base class is:

```
class OptionsBase
{
   protected:
        boost::program_options::options_description program_specific_options;
        void add_prog_specific_options_and_parse(int argc, char* argv[]);
   public:
        boost::program_options::variables_map   vm;
        OptionsBase(int argc, char* argv[]);
}
```

Defined as:

```
 OptionsBase::OptionsBase() : 
    program_specific_options(boost::program_options::options_description("Program-specific options")),
    vm() 
    {}

void OptionsBase::add_prog_specific_options_and_parse(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   try 
   {  boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::command_line_parser(argc,argv).options(program_specific_options).allow_unregistered().run(), vm);
      boost::program_options::notify(vm);
   }
   catch(std::exception& e)
   {
      std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
```

This is used in the Library in the following way:

```
class LibraryOptions : public OptionsBase
{
   const double get_something()     const {return vm["something"].as<double>();};
   LibraryOptions(int argc, char* argv[])
}
```

Definition:

```
LibraryOptions::LibraryOptions(int argc, char* argv[])
: BaseOptions()
{
   program_specific_options.add_options()
   ("something", boost::program_options::value<double>()->default_value(0.0), "some random program option");
    add_prog_specific_options_and_parse(argc, argv);

}
```

In the package that uses the Library, I wish to derive another class from `LibraryOptions`:

```
  class PackageOptions : public LibraryOptions
  {
     const double get_another_option() const {return vm["anotheroption"].as<double>();};
     PackageOptions(int argc, char* argv[])
  }
```

Definition:

```
PackageOptions::PackageOptions(int argc, char* argv[])
: LibraryOptions(argc,argv)
{
   program_specific_options.add_options()
   ("anotheroption", boost::program_options::value<double>()->default_value(5.0), "Extra options");
    add_prog_specific_options_and_parse(argc, argv);
}
```

Finally, I want to use this in the following way:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv [])
{
   PackageOptions opt(argc,argv);
   ComplexObject cob(opt);
   double a=cob.do_something();
}
```

where `ComplexObject` and `do_something` are:

```
class ComplexObject
{
   PackageOptions opt;
   double do_something() const
   {
      AnotherComplexObject calculator(opt);
      return calculator.do_something_else() * opt.get_another_option();
   };
   ComplexObject(const PackageOptions& _opt) : opt(_opt) {};
}

class AnotherComplexObject
{
   LibraryOptions opt;
   double do_something_else()
   {
       double b = opt.get_something(); // imagine really complex code that needs options from opt object
       return b;
   }
   AnotherComplexObject(const LibraryOptions& _opt) : opt(_opt) {};
}
```

So child `PackageOptions` needs to be upcasted to its parent `LibraryOptions` because `ComplexObject's` member function is creating `AnotherComplexObject` that is written to deal with `LibraryOptions` object.

I know this above seems redundant, as clearly one options class with all the options would resolve all the confusion. The variable map of the base class already ignores unregistered options, so this implementation seems overcomplicated. However, the real idea throughout my package is that `LibraryOptions` belongs to the library package and I am building a new package that uses it. Obviously, the new package has some additional options to the ones given by `LibraryOptions` object, which is why `PackageOptions` object makes sense.
I think that sending `PackageOptions` object when `LibraryOptions` object is needed should automatically upcast the child into parent and slice it, which is ok. I am mainly worried are these object correctly copying and moving with rule of 0 enforced above.

Overall, my questions are:

- Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? I noticed that I am calling add_prog_specific_options_and_parse(argc,argv) twice in `PackageOptions` constructor (first call is in `LibraryOptions` constructor.
- Do I need to default some constructors?
- Do I need virtual destructor in OptionsBase class?
- Would this work properly if I redesign my code to pass `std::shared_ptr<PackageOptions>` around? I think I am wasting some time coping `PackageOptions` and `LibraryOptions` objects in objects as `ComplexObject`. Object `ComplexObject` does not need to own the field `PackageOptions opt`, these options are mainly objects filled with convenient get_methods that access the variable map in the options class.

The code seems to be working and memory leak has been removed, I am just unsure if I implemented the code correctly.

Comment: If you are worried about copying, you should make these classes non-copyable, after all program options are the archetype of global data, or singleton (yes there will always be a reasonable use-case for singleton).  Do not make copies, after the options are parsed, program options should not change and are constant,  Constant data is always thread-safe, so you can safely use a const ref to a global object or from a singleton (which I think is best for this use-case, but that's a personal choice) to pass program options

Comment: @MichaëlRoy even logical singletons can simply be dependencies, which aids in testing, or e.g. running different package modules in one process. I agree with the simplifications regarding the design.

Comment: Personally the top review comment is that it feels out-of-line to `::exit` from `add_prog_specific_options_and_parse`. When you decouple command line handling from `main` - I would leave it up to the caller to handle exceptions (perhaps transform them into usable form)

Answer (score 1):

1. > Do I need to default some constructors?

   Only if you need default constructed instances. The compiler will tell you when this was required.
2. > Do I need virtual destructor in OptionsBase class?

   These are required in virtual types (*and*) when you could be deleting through  a pointer-to-base instead of the derived type.

   Yours types aren't virtual:

   ```
   #include <type_traits>
   static_assert(not(std::is_polymorphic_v<OptionsBase> || std::is_polymorphic_v<LibraryOptions> ||
                     std::is_polymorphic_v<PackageOptions>));
   ```

   (I did some renames to understand the hierarchy more clearly, see full listing below)

   Also, they're not dynamically allocated.
3. > Would this work properly if I redesign my code to pass std::shared_ptr around?

   Yes. To avoid any potential trouble make it `std::shared_ptr<PackageOptions const>` and live a happy life!

### Listing

Result of my review pass (I do active reading to see what is going on):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9cb5d9cae5697b9)**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace po = boost:: program_options;

class OptionsBase {
  protected:
    po::options_description program_specific_options;

    void add_prog_specific_options_and_parse(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        try {
            store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv)
                                             .options(program_specific_options)
                                             .allow_unregistered()
                                             .run(),
                                         vm);
            notify(vm);
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            std::cerr << "add_prog_specific_options_and_pars: " << e.what() << std::endl;
            ::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

  public:
    po::variables_map vm;
    OptionsBase()
        : program_specific_options(po::options_description("Program-specific options"))
        , vm() {}

    OptionsBase(int argc, char* argv[]);
};

class LibraryOptions : public OptionsBase {
  public:
    double get_something() const { return vm["libx"].as<double>(); };
    LibraryOptions(int argc, char* argv[]) : OptionsBase() {
        program_specific_options.add_options()                                              //
            ("libx", po::value<double>()->default_value(0.0), "some random program option") //
            ;
        add_prog_specific_options_and_parse(argc, argv);
    }
};

class PackageOptions : public LibraryOptions {
  public:
    double get_another_option() const { return vm["pkgx"].as<double>(); };
    PackageOptions(int argc, char* argv[]) : LibraryOptions(argc, argv) {
        program_specific_options.add_options()                                 //
            ("pkgx", po::value<double>()->default_value(5.0), "Extra options") //
            ;
        add_prog_specific_options_and_parse(argc, argv);
    }
};

class LibraryObject {
    LibraryOptions opt;

  public:
    double do_something_else() { return opt.get_something(); }
    LibraryObject(LibraryOptions const& _opt) : opt(_opt){};
};

class PackageObject {
    PackageOptions opt;

  public:
    double do_something() const {
        LibraryObject calculator(opt);
        return calculator.do_something_else() * opt.get_another_option();
    };
    PackageObject(PackageOptions const& _opt) : opt(_opt){};
};

#include <type_traits>
static_assert(not(std::is_polymorphic_v<OptionsBase> || std::is_polymorphic_v<LibraryOptions> ||
                  std::is_polymorphic_v<PackageOptions>));

#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <functional>
using boost::adaptors::transformed;
using namespace std::string_literals;

int main() {
    auto args = std::array{"programx"s, "--libx"s, "42"s, "--pkgx"s, "2"s};
    auto argv = copy_range<std::vector<char*>>(args | transformed([](auto& s) { return s.data(); }));
    argv.push_back(nullptr);

    PackageOptions opt(args.size(), argv.data());
    PackageObject  pob(opt);

    std::cout << pob.do_something() << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
84
```

Comment: I have a weird bug, one VeruComplexObject has int and double fields, and PackageOptions field. The double and int field started giving absolute nonsense in one of the methods (3.3e-317 and 6674147). The constructor of this object was VeryComplexObject(const Options &opt, int a, double b) : _opt(opt), _a(a), _b(b){...}. If I print _a and _b in the constructor, everything is fine, but in the method _a and _b are nonsense. These issues went away when I made std::shared_ptr<PackageOptions> opt(new PackageOptions(argc,argv)) in the main, and created VerComplexObject vcob(*opt,a,b). Any idea why?

Comment: I know this above makes little sense without a replicable example, but I am very confused. For some reason, state of the private fields of the VeryComplexObject has been altered, even though there was no method in the class that could do this (I added const modifier in all methods). And all seems to have originated from the way options class field was generated. Copying PackageOptions by the value was not working, while making it a shared pointer and dereferencing it as *opt, magically resolved the bug. I would like to understand why.

Comment: That sounds like dangling references. That's when you run with ASan/UBSan enabled or under something like Valgrind. Also possible you ended up with a [diamond class hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) but that's a longer stretch.